# Departure and arrival fix loading via FAA website

Tags: faa, departure-sid

About 8 years ago I was involved in a project that would hit an FAA website for fix loading. It was departure and arrival fixes and their associated data. The URL included a command line where you could request an airport, date, time, and increment. Does anyone know what happned to that site or if there is a replacement? The data looked something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you know the original URL you were using at the time?

Comment: It's an IP address.

Comment: All URLs correspond to an IP address. Would still be helpful if you could post it.

Answer (score 1):

The FAA has a graphical display of forecast arrivals by arrival fix for airports in the [Airport Arrival Demand Chart](https://www.fly.faa.gov/aadc/). Choose a time interval, airport, and select "arrival fix." If you look at what it's doing through a network inspector, you'll see it's fetching JSON data, if you're looking for programmatic access.

That page only shows arrivals, not departures though.

Comment: Very interesting. Let me follow up on that